# Im using position absolute but my elements doesnt stay on where i placed them when the window or screen size is changed

Tags: html, css

Im kind of new to web development. I was struggling to position HTML elements with position relative so i started to use position absolute for every website i made. The thing is i can position them easily with stuff like

```
top: 20%
left: 60%
```

everytime i have used this method to position elements when the screen or window size changed elements started to move off to different positions. I don't know how to properly move element so that they don't move off and stay in their position. I really need to learn how. Thanks

```css
.artstation_w {
  position: absolute;
  left: 47%;
  top: 157%;
}

.behance_w {
  position: absolute;
  left: 52%;
  top: 156.5%;
}

.instagram_w {
  position: absolute;
  left: 57%;
  top: 156.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <img class="aboutimg" src="hakkımda.png" alt="">
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.artstation.com/ayazata"><img border="0" class="artstation_w" src="iconfinder_27_Artstation_logo_logos_4373281.png"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.behance.net/bonusz"><img border="0" class="behance_w" src="iconfinder_77-behance_104426.png"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sametsylmz3d/"><img border="0" class="instagram_w" src="instagram-png-instagram-icon-png-50-px-512.png"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: plz add your example code ..

Comment: @AbdullahAlNoor i added an example code

Comment: add parent div to position relative

Comment: @RayeesAC No. That doesnt work. The elements still move off. I think there is a problem with using position absolute

Comment: you need to learn more about CSS and read tutorial about layouts. You have to get rid of position:absolute and use something else

Comment: Position absolute is "relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element" .

Comment: Please add expected output screenshot

Comment: @TemaniAfif You are right i think using absolute is bad sports. But that's why I'm asking this. What is normally used to position elements in css so that they don't move off?

Comment: position: absolute need  position: relative it;s parent element to work ..

Comment: there is a lot of ways that's why I suggest you to read more tutorials. Search around CSS layouts and you will get what you want

Comment: @FedericoProvenziani Yeah but then i cant position elements how I want to. What if I want a button to be slightly to the left?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Alright. Thanks everyone. I think ill do some more research

Comment: Elements position inside a page are never ever managed in this way. Imagine to have a page divided in more components or even in only one file. And at certain point you need to move some element... Imagine how it can be confusing changing parents position or element itself position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no quite sure what you are trying to accomplish ... but when you use percentage to position absolute elements , the percentage is relative to the screen width so each change of the screen width the left value will be different for each element..

if you wanna do this without them to change the space between them you can do it like this using 'transform'

```css
.artstation_w {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 157%;
  transform: translateX(-2rem);
}

.behance_w {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 156.5%;
}

.instagram_w {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 156.5%;
  transform: translateX(2rem);
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <img class="aboutimg" src="hakkımda.png" alt="">
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.artstation.com/ayazata"><img border="0" class="artstation_w" src="iconfinder_27_Artstation_logo_logos_4373281.png"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.behance.net/bonusz"><img border="0" class="behance_w" src="iconfinder_77-behance_104426.png"></a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/sametsylmz3d/"><img border="0" class="instagram_w" src="instagram-png-instagram-icon-png-50-px-512.png"></a>
  </p>
</div>
```

or if you wanna keep it your way , you gonna have to define the width of the absolute elements to be in percentage... because it has to change based on the screen width so you can keep the same distance between elements

anyway , avoid using that many absolute positioned elements, i'm sure there is another way to achieve the final result you are trying to get...

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me according to what you gave the values of the transforms? Like why 2rem or -2rem. Thanks!

Comment: It's up to you how much space you want to have between the elements... 2rem would be space between them ... use whatever you want